# how to subtract days or months from datetime using postgresql/netezza

Tags: postgresql, netezza

I have this sql query that is working fine but would like to convert it into some kind of postgresql or netezza equivalent query.  Here are my queries:

```
SELECT name, location, Date FROM myTable WHERE [Date] < DateAdd(hh, 48, [shipDate]
```

and other query

```
SELECT name, location, Date FROM myTable WHERE [Date] < DateAdd(d, 90, [shipDate]
```

Comment: Don use [brackets]. They are a Microsoft-extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Netezza the easiest thing to do is use an interval calculation:

```
SELECT name, location, Date FROM myTable WHERE Date < shipDate + interval '48 hours';
SELECT name, location, Date FROM myTable WHERE Date < shipDate + interval '2 days';
SELECT name, location, Date FROM myTable WHERE Date < shipDate + interval '90 days';
```

You can also use add_months if you want to do month calculations that are aware of the different length of the months.

```
SELECT name, location, Date FROM myTable WHERE Date < add_months(shipdate, 3);
```

Comment: There's no add_months() function in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I'll edit to clarify that my response is for the netezza part of "Postgres or netezza"

Comment: A word of warning: It is possible to define intervals with a months component, but you should avoid doing so as it introduces subtle date math errors. You can also add days using integer arithmetic, but again this introduces subtle errors. Always use add_months for units in months and years, and intervals for days, hours, minutes, and seconds. AFAICT there is no support for millisecond date math.